# Display and grab the value listed in the DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

My COntroller class;

in the following example `returnAllHuman();` will return  `List<SelectListItem>`

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = returnAllHuman(); // List<SelectListItem>

        ViewData["all_Human"] = list;
        return View();

    }
```

In the View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("all_Human")
```

1.) The values don't get displayed

2.) I need to grab the selected value and display it in a text field. How can i do this ?

UPDATE: I removed the exception handling part from the below code

```
  public List<SelectListItem> returnAllHuman()
    {
        var i = new List<SelectListItem>();


            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader s = com.ExecuteReader();


                while (s.Read())
                {
                    i.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = s.GetString(0), 
                        Text = s.GetString(1)  
                    });
                }

                           con.Close();



        return i;
    }
```

Comment: you are passing a select list (i think) but you are don't seem to be binding to a model value on the way to the View. Do you take a value in to your action method?

Comment: returnAllHuman() will have a Key and Value

Comment: maybe the problem is your list, can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

Start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SelectedHuman { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllHumans { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller populate this model and pass to the view:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.AllHumans = returnAllHuman(); // List<SelectListItem>
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // there was a validation error => for example the user didn't make
            // any selection => rebind the AllHumans property and redisplay the view
            model.AllHumans = returnAllHuman();
            return View(model);
        }

        // at this stage we know that the model is valid and model.SelectedHuman
        // will contain the selected value
        // => we could do some processing here with it
        return Content(string.Format("Thanks for selecting: {0}", model.SelectedHuman));
    }
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedHuman, Model.AllHumans, "-- Select --")
    @Html.ValidationFor(x => x.SelectedHuman)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: I already have a Model defined, therefore, i am unable to add another Model to the view. Is there another way to do this. May be by using ViewData or ViewBag ?

Comment: Then simply add the 2 properties (`SelectedHuman` and `AllHumans`) to your existing view model. I hope you are using a view model and not passing your domain models to the view, aren't you?

Comment: You said that you already had a view model, right? Do you see the 2 properties I have shown in my example? Simply add them to your existing view model and then you could also have other input fields for the other values in addition to the dropdown. The other logic will be exactly the same. Forget about `ViewData` and `ViewBag`. Those are notions that should never be used in an ASP.NET MVC application. In a properly designed ASP.NET MVC application you should be working with view models.

Comment: Ok, WHen i submit it (when i click the button), i end up getting this error `Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Did you repopulate the `AllHumans` property in your POST action before returning the same view as shown in my answer?